# Multiple infowindows Jinja Google maps and flask

Tags: python, google-maps, flask, infowindow, jinja2

I have been fighting this all day

The code below takes a jinja array from flask and providing I dont want an info box it all works hunky dory.

Add the infobox code below and it presents a single marker and no info window.  Its been driving me crazy.  I also want to use clustering as I have about 500 pins but that is such a second order problem.

I have had a look at SO tried many of the answers to no avail, there is some sort of magic called closure that seems to be at the heart of the problem that I clearly  don't get.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in anticipation

```
function initialize() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.455177, 12.584731),
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });


function addMarker(lat,long,name,content){
var info = content;
var message = name;
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
var newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point,
                                     map: map,
                                     title: name
                                    });
\\take this block of code out and I get all the markers fine 
 google.maps.AddListener(point, 'click', function(map, newmarker){
      infowindow.setContent(info)
      infowindow.open(map,newmarker)
  });
}

 {% for marker in markers %}  
         addMarker({{marker.lat}},{{marker.long}},'{{marker.name}}', '{{marker.url}}');        
 {% endfor %}
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Did you look at the javascript console?  You have a typo in your event listener.  `marker` doesn't exist, that variable is called `newmarker` in your code. `infowindow.open(map,newmarker)`

Comment: I had edited it, and it did of course have newmarkers in there - still failing to display all but the last pin with not infowindow when I add the listener :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the syntax for the event listener.

Should be `google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'click', function(evt){`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7f5D/)

Comment: GeocodeZIP would have nailed it if it was not for that pesky Jinja code.  the answer was to test of the python list was empty and if not then pass it through a filter See here:         `{% if theRecord %}
        var markers = {{ theRecord |tojson | safe}};
        {% endif %}`  Once that was done then all the standard examples that use `for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++)`  Just work.  thanks for the effort!

Comment: That was two filters not one, the Python List `theRecord` was converted to json which allowed array items to be indexed with markers[i].name  or markers[i].url  but only if it was further filterd using safe to allow escaped codes.  Hope this helps someone.